# Exact match on full text search

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to implement a boolean text search on postgresql for users to be able to build their own searches.

I've been following the full text search capabilities, it seems to be pretty good at finding singular words but I can't quite get it to work with exact matches.

I'd like to pass in the following `to_tsquery('europe | "hard brexit"')` but it seems not to like the quotes on the second part of that query.

```
SELECT title, ts_headline(article, keywords) AS result, rank
FROM (
    SELECT keywords, article, title, phrase, ts_rank(phrase, keywords, 2) AS rank
    FROM (
        SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS title, description AS article, to_tsvector(description) AS phrase
        FROM news.stories
    ) c, to_tsquery('europe | "hard brexit"') AS keywords
    WHERE phrase @@ keywords
    ORDER BY rank desc
    LIMIT 10
) r;
```

My question: Is it possible to use exact matches in full-text searches? If not how can a boolean text search be achieved within Postgresql?

**Edit:** I experimented with exact matches to: `to_tsquery('europe | hard <-> brexit')` but I'm not sure how similarly this works to an actual exact match.

Comment: Have you tried the websearch_to_tsquery function?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/textsearch-controls.html That one handles double quotes.

Comment: @Jeremy I wasn't aware of that but it does seem to suffer from the same problem, `hard <-> brexit` is not the same as `"hard brexit"` because the driving force is the lexemes, this means a search like "fox trot" would find and return "foxes trot" which would be totally unacceptable for an exact match. i.e. exact matches will be treated as fuzzy matches.

Comment: You could specify the simple configuration.  I believe that just converts everything to lower case. This returns false: select websearch_to_tsquery('simple', '"fox trot"') @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'the Foxes trot') ;

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have since tested and that works as expected, if you'd like to expand your comment into an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your main problem is the stemming; phrase search with `<->` should work just as you want it to.

You can avoid stemming by using a *text search configuration* that doesn't include a stemming dictionary (for example `simple`).